# If A is invertible then KerB=KerAB

Tags: linear-algebra

A is m*m matrix and B is a m*n matrix. Show that if A is invertible then KerB=KerAB.

I have been thinking that let x belongs to KerB so that Bx=0.
 A*A^-1*Bx=In*Bx=Bx

but dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen an arbitrary element $x \in \ker B$. You should prove that this element also lies in $\ker AB$, to show the inclusion $\ker B \subset \ker AB$. After that you'll also have to show the other inclusion, where you'll have to use the fact that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes I have shown that kerB⊂kerAB but dont know how to continue.

Comment: Let $x \in \ker AB$, ...

Comment: x∈kerAB so that ABx=0 and A^-1*ABx=Bx? could you explain a little bit more. thank you so much.emm.. I m not so familiar with invertible matrix..

Comment: Exactly, apply $A^{-1}$ to both sides of $ABx = 0$.

Comment: thank you so much ! I get it!

Answer (score 5):

We always have $\ker( B)\subseteq \ker (AB)$. Here we have an inverse of $A$ and hence  additionally $\ker(AB)\subseteq \ker(A^{-1}AB)=\ker(B)$.

Comment: I can understand KerB is a subset of KerAB but why is KerAB is a subset of KerA^-1AB?

Comment: @kiki For the exact same reason that $\ker(B)\subset \ker (AB)$.  Replace $B$ with $AB$ and $A$ with $A^{-1}$ in that statement.

Comment: thank you I have it done:)